# Как скрывать элементы интерфейса в зависимости от результата запроса в БД?

Tags: php, база-данных, postgresql, astra-linux

Запрос в базу возвращает данные, логическое значение истины или исключение в зависимости от того, какой пользователь сделать запрос и куда. Этот механизм реализован на PostgreSql AstraLinux по умолчанию. В процессе этого механизма, пользователя проверяет сама база и принимает решение о предоставлении доступа (выполнении запроса). Если доступ закрыт, то выкидывается исключение определенного типа.

Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом реализовать универсальный механизм, который мог бы скрывать элементы графического интерфейса в зависимости от результата запроса к базе. Под элементами интерфейса подразумеваются: кнопки, ссылки и прочие управляющие элементы.

Пример: если пользователь состоит в группе А, то скрыть кнопки добавления, редактирования и удаления.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, какое исключения Вы получаете. Либо добавьте код, либо более точное описание. Скрыть то данные не проблема и через `php`  и через `js`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb это понятно, с помощью чего можно скрыть, вопрос заключается именно в том, как это сделать универсально, чтобы не кидать `try` структуру перед каждой кнопкой. Причем тут какое исключение, тип его не имеет значение. Больше интересует алгоритм скрытия без костылей

Comment: Как вы определили, что данный пользователь состоит в группе А? Как вы определили, что кнопки добавления, редактирования, удаления не связаны с группой А?

Comment: @ArchDemon с помощью freeipa можно получить данные о пользователи сети (аналог ldap, но для astra linux). В теории, если назвать функциональные возможности (чтение и запись) и классифицировать их именно в группы ровно также как называются страницы (конечная часть ссылки), то будет адекватным решением? Просто не понятно как провести однозначное сравнивание раздела сайта и возможностей юзера в нем (в базе находится). В базе posthres можно сделать группы пользователей и прочее.

Comment: Аналогом LDAP в Астре является ALD. Прошу не путать. FreeIPA это над LDAP. Если у вас права в группах не пересекаются, то можете попробовать в url добавить название группы.